Azure HttpTrigger Function returns bad request
Below is the Azure function when hosted on Azure returns Bad request response with a http header "Accept-Encoding" with value of "gzip deflate". However this works fine on local setup.
    public class Function1
{
    [Function("Function1")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
    }
}

I understand the value of gzip deflate should have been gzip, deflate. Is there a way for me to substitute this value with the correct value of gzip, deflate or override the behavior of returning the bad request by the infrastructure?
I tried using the custom middleware workerApplication.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>(); this does not seem to solve the problem
Any insights into this issue is highly appreciated.
Sample Request:
curl --location 'https://<website>.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?code=7tv0BEWCJdpBmAqjKObYUl6VXtTJWsyUmOY3TjdmhP7nAzFu-o0avw%3D%3D' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip deflate'

Response:


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <h2>Bad Request</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY>

</HTML>




I'm able to run the function in portal, check Image1,Image2

from portal it works. if you try from post man / fiddler it does not

you have to use gzip-deflate, worked for me image

Thanks for the suggestion. Caller to our function sending this header is not in our control. So I cannot change the value. I am pursuing with them to change. But it is not in our control. I am trying to understand if we can intercept and correct from our end to say to the correct format gzip, deflate

Is it okay to skip the Accept-Encoding header in the command and set in it the function code?

Caller is going to always send this header. As I indicated earlier, we do not have control on the caller. If we can some how inform the infrastructure to ignore/ change/ update this header so that our logic can be processed is what I am looking for..
